# Does a distribution of difference-in-means, be considered as distribution of means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, t-test

I have mean sales data of a product, pre & post an `event`, for a list of countries.
i.e I have 2 sales value for a product per country.

My aim is to see if there is statistically significant increase in the sales (if post>pre) due to the event.

When doing a t-test on the `difference in mean` ((post-pre)/max(post, pre)), I get the CI interval (90%) to be above 0, indicating increase in sales is statistically significant.

But when doing a paired t-test between the 2 `means` (across all countries), i.e if there is statistically significant increase in mean of post mean-values compared to pre mean-values, here it is not statistically significant, p>0.10 (CI 90%)

Question 1. Why the difference in statistical significance? Something wrong in my approach ?

Question 2. Can I rely on the statistical significance of the Mean-Difference ?

Comment: The paired t-test basically is a t-test of the difference in means, so if you did everything correctly, results should be the same. We can't know why they aren't, as we can't see what precisely you have done.

Comment: Note however that the CI is usually associated to a *two-sided* test whereas the way you explain your problem suggests that you may want to run a *one-sided* test. If one of your tests was one-sided and the other one two-sided, this would explain why you get different results.